# Unusual UITableView crash on -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've searched a ton and haven't found an answer that seems to address the problem I'm having.

I have a UITableViewController. In the viewDidLoad method I load objects from a database and then call reloadData.

Now generally this works fine. However, now I'm implementing sorting, which is persisted so that the same sorting algorithm is used on the next app launch. Note in all cases, the size of the array backing the section is the same after sorting.

If I use the default sorting method, I get no crash, even though it runs through the same sort > call delegate > reloadTable code path. However, if I use an alternate sorting method, which uses the same code path, I see the table view ask for number of rows, and get the correct number, but then I get this exception. Only the objects are sorted in a different order, so this makes no sense to me.

Also of note is that if I sort the objects (which uses the same code path) after the table has been displayed, it works fine.

This makes no sense to me, and almost seems like a UITableView bug, but I hope it's something I can fix.

My app is open source, so I can link directly to the relevant files:

https://github.com/einsteinx2/iSub/blob/weird_crash/Classes/UI/Reusable/ItemViewController.swift
https://github.com/einsteinx2/iSub/blob/weird_crash/Classes/UI/Reusable/ItemViewModel.swift

The most relevant methods are `ItemViewModel.sortAll()` and `ItemViewController.itemsChanged(viewModel: ItemViewModel)`

I've run out of ideas on how to debug this. It just makes no sense.

Some trial and error things I've tried:

1. Using only one table section
2. Calling reloadData after a delay to rule out some kind of race condition
3. Not calling reloadData in my itemsChanged delegate method (still crashes, as reloadData seems to be called automatically by the table view controller)

Nothing seems to make any difference. I'm completely confused how this could be possible. If anyone has any ideas on how I can continue to debug this, or how it may be possible, I'm all ears. Thanks.

EDIT: To make matters more confusing, I have similarly persisted sorting for albums, which use the same ItemViewController, however returning to an album that was previously sorted does not cause a crash, even though it should be doing the exact same thing and running the same code path.

Comment: What architecture are you following in the project? :?

Comment: If I understand your question properly, it's sort of MVVM but with no bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I finally figured it out and talk about edge case!

Turns out the crash has to do with the table section indexes (the letters on the right hand side), not the actual data loading or sorting.

I was using the unicode bullet character `•` when not sorted by name. Somehow this worked when you sorted live, but there is some bug in UITableView that causes the internal array of section indexes to be empty when you load the table with that data. I switched to using the black circle character `●` and now it no longer crashes.

I think this has to be the smallest change for the most amount of investigation work I've ever done in 8 years of coding for iOS.

Hope this helps some random person in the future. I'll report a bug to Apple, though likely it won't be high priority so who knows if/when they'll fix it.